# Can't install g++ Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: g++

I tried "sudo apt-get install g++" 
I got a long string of

```
qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin is already the newest version.
gnome-power-manager is already the newest version.
```

Ending in:
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

However when I go back trying to run a program "g++ -o Hello Hello.cpp" but I get the

```
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
   sudo apt-get install g++
```

EDIT:

```
apt-cache policy g++-4.8

    g++-4.8:
      Installed: (none)
      Candidate: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
      Version table:
         4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
            500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

sudo apt-get install g++-4.8

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     g++-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
               Depends: gcc-4.8 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
               Depends: libstdc++-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy g++-4.8; sudo apt-get install g++-4.8`

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add output of `apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install g++` and `echo q | aptitude -s install g++`

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the updates in your question, you have disabled the trusty-updates repository

Open <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>, open the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd> and activate the check box for <kbd>Recommended updates</kbd>

[image]

Now install the package again

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependecies: g++ : Depends: g++-4.8 (>=  4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.